# Low Quality Google.getUrlPhoto(); (ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to get the full quality photo from GoogleSignInAccount (ANDROID STUDIO).

This is what i want URL = [Photo1](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kJo1HK_MRwsFWcgp6gqGzVF-L-QDGE8fAryFGwLwt22NBkeJMoaqJyJHPRs1ZSXIq3wE6EK6jkb6=w722-h720-rw-no)
This is what i get URL = [Photo2](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bGe7RVVggTk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACY/Us2saWNwMUQ/s96-c/photo.jpg)

Does anyone know what I should do?
// CODE

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();
```

// i implement a class to Sign in with google, all works fine, but google gives a low quality photo in his url.

// IN MainActivity OnCreate ->

```
 googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if(googleSignInAccount != null){
        String url = googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl();
    }
```

and then i receive the [Photo2](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bGe7RVVggTk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACY/Us2saWNwMUQ/s96-c/photo.jpg) but a want [Photo1](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kJo1HK_MRwsFWcgp6gqGzVF-L-QDGE8fAryFGwLwt22NBkeJMoaqJyJHPRs1ZSXIq3wE6EK6jkb6=w722-h720-rw-no)

Comment: can you please paste the code where you are doing this ?

Comment: @IDroid there are the code

Comment: but that code is for the sign in part and not for the file upload and downlaod

Comment: i think you are getting just the thumbnail of the photo with getPhotoUrl();

Comment: refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931578/googlesigninaccount-getphotourl-return-null     and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the end scalling with other known scale (256, 512, 640, etc). In your case, you have a `96` scale

[https://...Us2saWNwMUQ/s96-c/photo.jpg](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bGe7RVVggTk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACY/Us2saWNwMUQ/s96-c/photo.jpg)

You can make it bigger by replacing `s96` with `s1080` so you get

[https://...Us2saWNwMUQ/s1080-c/photo.jpg](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bGe7RVVggTk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACY/Us2saWNwMUQ/s1080-c/photo.jpg)

Comment: Thanks a lot :D :D :D