# Google+ DEPRECATED and GoogleSignInAccount getPhotoUrl() return null

Tags: android, google-api

I am trying to get the Google profile Photo Url using GoogleSignInAccount class, after signing in with GoogleSignIn:

```
[...]
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
Uri photoUrl = MainActivity.account.getPhotoUrl();
[...]
```

but `photoUrl` is always null. I read on Stackoverflow ([GoogleSignInAccount getPhotoUrl() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931578/googlesigninaccount-getphotourl-return-null)) that it return NULL if Google+ is not well configurated.
The main problem is: Google+ has closed on 2 april 2019.

***How can I get the Google profile photo URL now?***

Comment: it's not deprecated, it's obsoleted: https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with your code and from the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people)

> Note that any of the profile fields can be null, depending on which scopes you requested and what information the user's profile includes.

photo url for the Google account. Only non-null if requestProfile() is configured and user does have a Google+ profile picture.

And since google plus has been deleted , that makes a sense that `getPhotoUrl` returns null

Comment: But why is my 'Profile photo url' null? I set it up

Comment: @AndreaFortunato it's `null` simply because they've deleted it.

Comment: Is there another way to get the photo profile or photo profile url?

Comment: i don't think so actually

Comment: please consider my answer if it answer your question